# SQL: Combine tables and order all rows / Avoid storing lots of null data

Tags: sql, postgresql

Typically in SQL `JOINS` requires you to join two tables `ON` a specific column, and then rows get merged. That isn't what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to join tables in SQL in a way that you can `ORDER BY` columns with the same name, such that x rows are returned, where x = the sum of rows in table 1 and table 2.

To hopefully clarify what I mean, here's an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM (combined Real and Placeholder items)
ORDER BY StartDate, OnDayIndex
```

and here's what results might look like:

```
ID     OnDayIndex   StartDate     ItemType      Name         TemplatePointer
12308   2           1996-09-18    Real          Actual Name  Null
10309   11          1996-09-19    Placeholder   Null         123
30310   5           1996-09-20    Real          Actual Name  Null
30410   6           1996-09-20    Placeholder   Null         456
```

My use case is a calendar application with recurring events. To save space, it doesn't make sense to store every recurrence of an event. If it weren't for the particulars of my use case I'd just store a template with a rule and recurring events would be generated when viewed, except for one-off events. The problem is the calendar app I'm working on allows you to move items around in the day they're and saves way you order the items. I'm already using a ranked model gem (link here: https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model) to cut down on the number of writes needed to update the "onDayIndex". The template approach on its own turns into a bit of a nightmare when "onDayIndex" is factored in... (I could say more...)

So I'd like to store slimmed down 'Placeholder' items that store the items' position and a pointer to template, perhaps in a separate table if possible.

If this isn't possible, an alternative approach I've considered for conserving space is moving most columns from the `Items` table to an `ItemData` table, and storing an `ItemDataID` on `Items`.

But I'd really like to know if it is possible, as I'm pretty junior in SQL, as well as any other vital information I may be missing.

I'm using Rails with a Postgres database.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it.

Comment: @MatBailie, if you'd like to write that as an official answer, I'll accept it. Alternately, if you think this question isn't useful, let me know and I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about using `UNION` / `UNION ALL` to stack result sets on top of each other, but where the sources have different columns?

If so, ***you*** need to fill in the 'missing' columns *(you can only `UNION` two sets if their signatures match, or can be coerced to match)*.

For example...

```
SELECT col1, col2, NULL as col3
  FROM tbl1

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, NULL AS col2, col3
  FROM tbl2
```

Note: `UNION` expends additional resources to remove duplicates from the results.  Use `UNION ALL` if such effort is wasted.